# как запустить свой index.html на XAMPP

Tags: html, веб-программирование, xampp

Скачала Xampp, запустила Apache, в папке htdocs создала папку с названием своего сайта и туда перенесла index.html файл. Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно запустить свой сайт с локального сервера?
Если запустить html файл прямо с папки, то не отображаются ни стили, ни эффекты (что и следовало ожидать, но надежда была)[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Название сайта Pulse, на картинке видна эта папка, которую я создала
Open Server Panel скачивала до этого, но предполагаю что из-за каких-то багов не открывается приложение. Поэтому решила перейти на Xampp. Я - новичок, так что не судите строго. Перечитала уже десятки сайтов и вроде как уже много что перепробовала.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как в браузере вы открываете сайт? По какому адресу?

Comment: http://localhost:3002/ это если я с vs code запускаю

Comment: А зачем там порт? .... нужно открывать localhost/pulse/index.html

Comment: А не смущает что index.html нет физически? (на скринах во всяком случае)

Comment: VC Code сам свой сервер запускает, он не имеет к xampp никакого отношения

Comment: html есть в папке pulse. Он скопирован из проекта

Comment: дело в том что мне нужно настроить mailer чтобы отправлялись с сайта письма на почту и для этого нужен локальный сервер

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1573812/#comment2836911_1573812

Comment: Помимо index.html, Вам нужно туда скопировать весь проект целиком.

Comment: я перенесла все папки что были в проекте, а как это запустить теперь? )

Comment: Понятно, мой коммент игнорируют.......окей

Comment: ну я курсы прохожу и там сказано установить локальный сервер. Даже если я ввожу http://localhost/pulse/index.html страница не грузится

Comment: не грузится - что это значит? опять со стилями беда или даже html не работает? перезапустите сервер..... а в консоли браузера посмотрите есть ли ошибки..............а также вопрос: в папке pulse есть файл index.html?

Comment: даже html не работает.

Comment: в папке pulse есть html, но мне тут подсказали что нужно не файлы из src грузить а из dist. Другой вопрос в том, как перетащить все в dist? там ничего нет

Comment: Какой ещё src  какой ещё dist? вам стОит задать вопрос всё же нормально...что у вас есть, какие файлы, какая структура и что вы хотите... сейчас из итогого вопроса начинает складываться какая-то каша со всё новыми вводными непонятными данными, которые известны только вам

Comment: извините) итак, есть проект https://github.com/JuliePahopol/pulse_project.git его структуру можно посмотреть тут. в данный момент все файлы находятся в папке src. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы заявка пользователя на сайте приходила письмом на почту. Для этого мне нужно подключить локальный сервер. Мне подсказали, что вероятно мне не удается это сделать, потому что файлы, которые я загружаю в папку pulse в xampp (в htdocs) приходят из src , хотя должны по идее из dist. Я надеюсь что на этот раз все написала) извините, что путаница вышла. Я-новичок и только учусь правильно формулировать вопросы)

Comment: Для того, чтобы отправлялись письма с сайта никакой локальный сервер не нужен. Более того с локального будет крайне проблематично что-то отправить (на это нужны ещё более глубокие знания, чем отсутствующие). Нужно бросать такие курсы, они ничему путёвом не научат.

Comment: @юля `Для этого мне нужно подключить локальный сервер` кмк там имелось ввиду не "пользовательско-локальный" а "админско-локальный" ну т.е. это не значит на своей домашней машинке. локальный вообще не это значит, нужно скорее - "находящийся в той же сети, в которой и сервак самого проекта"(применимо к обычным VDS иль как их там...) ну как то так пожалуй... а вообще стоит посмотреть в доки того с чем имеете дело, там наверняка есть хоть какие то уточнения. p.s. как на git'е подключить почту да и возможно ли это - понятия не имею, еще не интересовался таким, в настройки гит-акка гляньте :-/